# How to trigger build based on a custom tag and before build verify what code to build on

Tags: git, jenkins

I would likte to trigger a build based on commiting a custom tag ie "RNX"
But the tag will determine what portion of the code to build.
The tag correspond to a specific configuration in a folder with several configuration folders, but I only want to build one at a time.

Each configuration folder contains a file with a unique tag name.
Each folder also has its own gradle file.

My idea is to iterate over the configuration folders and compare the tag.txt files content  (holding the unique tag name) and execute gradle when a match is found. 
Can it be done?
I would need an example of at least somthing similar if possible, thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

You can set up a webhook in order to build on a tag and you can take this put in the Jenkinsfile and run whatever you want with this parameter "tag" like

```
sh "/${tag}/myconfig.sh"
```

Answer (score 0):

Im doing this by capture the tag on a post-receive hook and check if the tag name starts with 'STG'. if so, i consider it a staging tag, and trigger a CI job (which builds, test, merge, push, etc.)

Gitlab post-receive hook:

```
#!/bin/sh 
jenkins_job="CIJOB"
group="DEV"
project="myproj"
logfile="hook.log"

while read oldrev newrev refname
do
  echo "================================================" >> $logfile
  date                                                    >> $logfile
  echo "custom hook: running by pushing to $project.git " >> $logfile
  echo "oldrev: $oldrev"                                  >> $logfile
  echo "newrev: $newrev"                                  >> $logfile
  echo "refname: $refname"                                >> $logfile

  # check if branch/tag pushed
  unset branch
  unset tag

  # POSIX style 'if contains'
  if [ "${refname#*refs/heads}" != "$refname" ]; then
    branch=$(echo $refname | cut -d'/' -f3)
    echo "branch pushed: $branch"                         >> $logfile
  else 
    tag=$(echo $refname | cut -d'/' -f3)
    echo "tag pushed: $tag"                               >> $logfile
  fi

  isStagingTag=$(echo $tag | grep "^STG-")
  if [ "X" != "X$isStagingTag" ] ; then
    echo "${tag} tag pushed, running CI"                   >> $logfile
    curl -X GET "http://user:pass@jenkins:8080/job/$jenkins_job/buildWithParameters?token=$jenkins_job&REPO=$project&REF=$refname&TAG=$tag"
  fi
done
```

Jenkins Job (pipeline):

```
#!groovy
node('slave7') {
  stage {
    // strip the 'STG-' prefix from tag name 
    TAG = TAG.substring(TAG.indexOf('-')+1)

    // here u can implement your logic using groovy
    println TAG

    // or POSIX shell
    sh """
      echo ${TAG}
    """
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you're using GitLab and the [GitLab Plugin](https://github.com/jenkinsci/gitlab-plugin) you can use the value of `gitlabActionType` and `gitlabTargetBranch` environment variables.

When you push a tag, `gitlabActionType` value will be `TAG_PUSH` and `gitlabTargetBranch` value will be the pushed tag.

So, for building the specific tag, you can do:

```
if (env.gitlabActionType == 'TAG_PUSH') {
    sh "${env.gitlabTargetBranch.split('/').last()}/build.sh"
}
```

Or:

```
if (env.gitlabActionType == 'TAG_PUSH') {
    dir("${env.gitlabTargetBranch.split('/').last()}") {
        sh "./build.sh"
    }
}
```

Also, you can filter what tags will launch the build: [More info in the official doc](https://github.com/jenkinsci/gitlab-plugin#build-when-tags-are-pushed)